# Why Wordpress does not keep file changes on Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customizing

Since the Wordpress new version (4.3 Billie) the changes made on the files of Woocommerce, for customizing reports, for example, does not rest for long. After a while, the original files apears again and the chages desapeare.

I don't know how to solve this. If its a coding issue or something about restrictions on the new version.